# creating nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-resources

I have a question that bothers me every time I face the same situation.

How to create a nested resource..

I have the following repo

```
 https://github.com/abhishekdagarit/app-e-commerce.git
```

You can clone the repo and create the dabtabase to see the project.

I need to add categories to the products..

```
 product
    belongs_to_and_has_many :categories

 category
    has_many :products
```

Could anyone please tell me how to achieve this to work properly...
I added comments to individual products but that took me four hours to achieve that...

This is what I normally do...

```
  1). add the category model using 
       rails g model category category_type:string

  2). then add the has_to and the belongs_to_and_has_many in the models

  3). add the controller 
       rails g controller categories

  4). add the following lines in the categories controller
       class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
       def new
         @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
         @category = @product.categories.build
         respond_with(@category)
       end
      def create
         @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
         @category = @product.categories.create(params[:category])
         redirect_to product_path(@product)
      end
     end
```

Now the thing is that these steps just don't seem to work...

I need someone to help me with the few lines to code that work in order to create a nested resource...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) from rails guides.

did you try the following nested resources?

```
resources :categories do
    resources :products
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to checkout:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2